# Are facebook graph user ids unique?

Tags: facebook, graph

Currently I'm creating an app using Facebook login.

What I've noticed is that my own user id is different by some digits when I use the graph explorer from the user id I get when I login using the I've coded.

So I'm guessing the "user id" is not unique, right? How can I ensure the uniqueness of a facebook user?

Thanks

Comment: Yes the are unique. But each app have their set of unique user ids. The Graph Explorer app is different from your app

Answer (score 2):

The User ID is unique, but only in the App. See "App-scoped User IDs" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You can also match App Scoped IDs of different Apps with the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business